# setting html form parameters on php class just like set property * in jsp usebean

Tags: php, jsp

Jsp is having following tags to take html form data on java bean.

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="login.model.User"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user" />
```

Do we have such thing in PHP.
Thanks in advance.